# Suppose we have a strictly increasing function $f$ such that $f'(x) \geq 2xf(x)$ under the interval $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a strictly increasing function $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) \geq xf(x)+x$ under the interval $(0,1)$. It is known that $f(0)=0$. How would one find the minimum value of $f(1)$, given that $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and differentiable in $(0,1)$?

I tried using the AM-GM inequality to get that $f'(x) \geq 2f(x)$ and the fact that the integral of $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is $\ln(f(x)) + c$, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: You shouldn't hide the original question, even in a comment - put it front and center, and then put your own re-interpretation after it. Also, presumably $f$ is minimized when $f'$ is, i.e. $f'=xf^2+x$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As for the minimization, f' is not defined with the inequality when x = 1 as the bound is not inclusive, so im not sure how that would be useful?

Comment: Your title does not match the body. Given the edit history, I guess you are really interested in the differential inequality $f'(x)\geq xf(x)^2+x$.

Comment: My bad i mistyped the title it should be fixed

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f'(x)$ known on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)$ is known, then $f(1)$ is determined. It doesn't matter if $f'(1)$ is defined or what it is.

Comment: It might be useful to solve $y^\prime=xy^2+x$. We know that $(\tan x)^\prime=\tan^2x+1$ so $y=\tan(x^2/2)$ would seem to meet the conditions.

Comment: But wouldn't the tangent function simply be one such function that meets the requirement, not necessarily minimizing f(1)?

Comment: (Did you read the part of my comment where I said $f$ is minimized when $f'$ is?)

Comment: Why did you remove the question text?

Comment: I'd like to study this problem but it seems it's been altered by someone and it does not make sense, and it's not too easy to read the mathjax from the edit history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem applied to the function $x \mapsto \arctan f(x) - \frac{x^2}{2}$ on $[0, 1]$, it follows that there exists $\xi \in (0, 1)$ satisfying

$$ \arctan f(1) - \frac{1}{2}
= \frac{f'(\xi)}{1+f(\xi)^2} - \xi
\geq 0. $$

So $f(1) \geq \tan(1/2)$ for any such function $f$. Moreover, this lower bound is achieved by the function $f(x) = \tan(x^2/2)$. Therefore the answer is $\tan(1/2)$.

Comment: I understand everything except for the part where you claim that f(1) >= tan(1/2) for all functions f. Why is this the case?

Comment: @kruskal123, $\tan(\cdot)$ is an increasing function on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, and so, you can apply $\tan(\cdot) $ to both sides of the inequality $\arctan f(1) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ which we already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that to minimize $f$ we must minimize $f'$ at every point, i.e. make the inequality into an equality. Solving that would use separation of variables:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2+1}=x\,\mathrm{d}x \quad \implies \quad \tan^{-1}(y)=\frac{x^2}{2} $$

(The constant of integration is $0$ since $f(0)=0$.)

To make this rigorous, note the inequality is equivalent to

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\tan^{-1}(y)\right]\ge x. $$

Inequalities may be (definitely) integrated, so apply $\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x$ to both sides to get

$$ \tan^{-1}(y)\ge \frac{x^2}{2}. $$

Thus $f(x)\ge\tan(x^2/2)$, and $f(1)\ge\tan(1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe,

$$  \frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2} = [\tan^{-1}f(x)]'\geq x $$

Integrate both sides over $x \in (0,1)$ with starting value $f(0) = 0$,

$$\tan^{-1}f(1)\ge\frac12$$

Thus,

$$f(x)\ge \tan\frac12$$

Comment: doesn't the integration only work when the inequality is defined at 0 and 1 (which it is not)?

Comment: It'd work in the sense of limits.